# Android firebase orderByKey doesn't change anything

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was searching for two days now, but the firebase topic is really poorly discussed i guess

I want to sort my data from firebase DB to get the weights from the newest to the oldest. I was trying to do it directly with `ref.orderByKey` and with         `Query refQuery = ref.orderByKey();` but none seems to work.

The key is a date with `yy:MM:dd` format, but with that code i'm getting data not sorted in any possible way... Any help?

[image: screenshot]

```
final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.com/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/weight/");

ref.orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        weights = new Double[(int)snapshot.getChildrenCount()];
        dates = new String[(int)snapshot.getChildrenCount()];
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wczytuje Pierwsze Dane"+snapshot.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int i = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            weights[i] = child.getValue(Double.class);
            dates[i] = child.getKey();
            weightMap.put(child.getKey(), child.getValue(Double.class));
            i++;
        }
        testowy.setText(""+weightMap.size());

        if(weightMap.size()>1)
        diffValue.setText(""+(weights[weightMap.size()-1] - weights[weightMap.size()-2]));

        WeightListAdapter weightList = new WeightListAdapter(weightMap);
        ListView weightListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightList);
        weightListView.setAdapter(weightList);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
     }
 });
```

Edit 1:

```
 ref.orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                 weights = new Double[(int)snapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                                                 dates = new String[(int)snapshot.getChildrenCount()];

                                                 int i = 0;
                                                 for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                     weights[i] = child.getValue(Double.class);
                                                     dates[i] = dt.format(Long.parseLong(child.getKey()));
                                                     weightMap.put(child.getKey(), child.getValue(Double.class));
                                                     i++;
                                                 }
```

I stood without converting the date for clarity of the question.The snapshot comes unsorted. Why...?

[image: screenshot]

Edit 2:
Is this what you asked me for?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've solved it.

Hashmap doesn't keep order of it's items. I used LinkedHashMap instead and it works now ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Try to format your date in milliseconds and then store it to
  database.
- Its better to convert your date in millisecond and then store it to the database and then convert it back when retrieved from db.

Otherwise,

- If you have set date as your key and can't change it then add
  **time** as a child (where data like weight is available) and apply sort on that child. Store millisecond on time.
- And use this :- `ref.orderByChild("time").addLis...`

**Updated :**

- Replace this

  ```
  final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.com/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/weight/");
  ```

  - with this

    ```
     final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.com/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/weight/hiper-diet-keeper/UBwsiRUqZrarupNRS/");
    ```

and use `ref.orderByKey()`

Comment: Thank you, the idea is perfect for me, but it still doesn't sort.
I'll update the question in a sec. 
(I can't put photos in comment, can I?)

Comment: Try to replace `ref.orderByKey()` with `ref.orderByChild("time")` and if its not working then show me your firebase db snapshot (snap of structure)

Comment: Newbie question - what is snap of structure? How can i get it?
And btw - why doesn't orderByKey doens't work?

Comment: I mean snapshot of structure. Just go to your firebase database and give me a snapshot of your database. By the way, `ref.orderByChild("time")` is not working??

Comment: Sorry, i've made a horrible mess. I replaced 'hiper-diet-keeper' with 'myapp' so it was more readable. I've already deleted "/weight/" from the url, so it's exactly what you are sayin' and it's not working either. I don't understand it at all. I put 'orderByKey', by value, by child, and it's allways in some random way. It's never by key, neither the value or child.

Comment: Hmm, we can just try you know. Try to access without `orderByKey()` now it will be `ref.addListener...`. See if it works.

Comment: Without change. The same order